# Find the mode across multiple columns for each row of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mode

I am new to Python and Pandas. I want to find the most common item for each row for columns Opt_1 to Opt_7. Note for some reason some of the blank cells appear to have NaN and in other cases it has None.

```
ID  Col_1   Col_2   Opt_1   Opt_2   Opt_3   Opt_4   Opt_5   Opt_6   Opt_7 
1   Game 1  Team 1  13                       
2   Game 1  Team 2  -13                      
3   Game 1  Team 1                           
4   Game 1  Team 2                           
5   Game 2  Team 1  -7.5    -7.5    -7.5    -7.5             
6   Game 2  Team 2  7.5     7.5     7.5     7.5          
7   Game 2  Team 1          -2.5    -1.5             
8   Game 2  Team 2          2.5     1.5          
9   Game 3  Team 1          3.5     3.5          
10  Game 3  Team 2          -3.5    -3.5             
11  Game 3  Team 1  -1      -1.5    -1       
12  Game 3  Team 2  1       1.5     1
```

I already tried the following code, which worked as expected for most rows, but not all. And it was a bit slow.

```
def freq_value(series):
    return Counter(series).most_common()[0][0]

for row in df.iterrows():
     df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: freq_value((row['Opt_1'], row['Opt_2'], row['Opt_3'], row['Opt_4'], row['Opt_5'], row['Opt_6'], row['Opt_7'])), axis=1)
```

Below is the expected results and the actual results:

```
ID  Expected    Actual Result
1   NaN         NaN
2   NaN         NaN
3   NaN         NaN
4   NaN         NaN
5   -7.5            -7.5
6   7.5         7.5
7   NaN         NaN
8   NaN         NaN
9   3.5         3.5
10  -3.5           -3.5
11  -1          NaN
12  1           NaN
```

Is there anyway of doing this so it is 100% correct, and perhaps done without iterating through each row one at a time? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Which spots were None, and which spots were NaN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` to select columns and `mode` + `mask` to find unique modes only:

```
(df.filter(like='Opt')
   .mode(axis=1)
   .set_axis(['a', 'b'], axis=1, inplace=False)
   .eval('a.mask(b.notna())', engine='python'))

0     13.0
1    -13.0
2      NaN
3      NaN
4     -7.5
5      7.5
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      3.5
9     -3.5
10    -1.0
11     1.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

`mode` will return *all* modes for a given row. This means that if there are two values that are equally frequent, there will be two columns in the output. The solution above handles the case when there are at most two columns.

If the mode is unique, the solution can be simplified to

```
df.filter(like='Opt').mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

---

Another solution when there is no unique mode, this will generalise to any number of columns in the output.

```
u = df.filter(like='Opt').mode(axis=1)
if len(u.columns) > 1:
    u = u.iloc[:, 0].where(u.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1))

u
0     13.0
1    -13.0
2      NaN
3      NaN
4     -7.5
5      7.5
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      3.5
9     -3.5
10    -1.0
11     1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'ID': range(1, 13),
...     'Col_1': [*(['Game 1'] * 4), *(['Game 2'] * 4), *(['Game 3'] * 4)],
...     'Col_2': ['Team 1', 'Team 2'] * 6,
...     'Opt_1': [13, -13, np.nan, np.nan, -7.5, 7.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -1, 1],
...     'Opt_2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -7.5, 7.5, -2.5, 2.5, 3.5, -3.5, -1.5, 1.5],
...     'Opt_3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -7.5, 7.5, -1.5, 1.5, 3.5, -3.5, -1, 1],
...     'Opt_4': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -7.5, 7.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
...     'Opt_5': [np.nan] * 12,
...     'Opt_6': [np.nan] * 12,
...     'Opt_7': [np.nan] * 12
... })
>>> df
    ID   Col_1   Col_2  Opt_1  Opt_2  Opt_3  Opt_4  Opt_5  Opt_6  Opt_7
0    1  Game 1  Team 1   13.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1    2  Game 1  Team 2  -13.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2    3  Game 1  Team 1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3    4  Game 1  Team 2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4    5  Game 2  Team 1   -7.5   -7.5   -7.5   -7.5    NaN    NaN    NaN
5    6  Game 2  Team 2    7.5    7.5    7.5    7.5    NaN    NaN    NaN
6    7  Game 2  Team 1    NaN   -2.5   -1.5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
7    8  Game 2  Team 2    NaN    2.5    1.5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
8    9  Game 3  Team 1    NaN    3.5    3.5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
9   10  Game 3  Team 2    NaN   -3.5   -3.5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
10  11  Game 3  Team 1   -1.0   -1.5   -1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
11  12  Game 3  Team 2    1.0    1.5    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
>>> opts = ['Opt_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 8)]
>>> df[opts].mode(axis=1, dropna=False)
      0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4  -7.5
5   7.5
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  NaN
11  NaN
```

Comment: thanks @Kyle Roth for your response. I like how you put the dataframe together, particularly how you put together column 1 and column 2. For your solution, I was a bit surprised for IDs 9:12 it didn't return 3.5, -3.5, -1.0 & 1.0 respectively as the mode. ps I can't remember how I found some blanks had NaN and others None.